# Feasible for China to stop all VPN use within its borders?

Tags: vpn

Is it technically feasible for China to stop all VPN use within its borders?

A slightly narrower goal might be to stop all new users of VPNs within its borders while doing nothing about temporary visitors that are travelling and carrying their own computers and phones. Is the narrower goal technically feasible?

Comment: How would they distinguish citizens from visitors?

Comment: @EsaJokinen China wouldn't have to. The visitors would install and subscribe to VPN services before arriving in China.

Answer (score 3):

From the technical perspective it is possible to distinguish common VPN traffic from "normal" traffic because of traffic patterns like talking only to specific servers (instead of talking to lots of servers), using specific ports, using specific protocols which can be detected with deep packet inspection ... .  There are ways to obfuscate the VPN protocol to look similar to normal traffic and there are ways to bypass currently employed detection methods - but what is detected and how it can be bypassed is continuously evolving. Also in order to reduce the risk of blocking "useful" traffic in case of false positives they might just disturb connections a bit, like dropping only some but not all packets, slowing packets down etc. For a technical deep dive into this topic I recommend [How the Great Firewall of China Detects and Blocks Fully Encrypted Traffic](https://gfw.report/publications/usenixsecurity23/en/) and other publications from [Great Firewall Report](https://gfw.report/).

As for distinguishing visitors and locals: for mobile connections the user could simply be distinguished by the SIM card they use and the mobile service provider could use  government allowed tunnels to pass these connections to the GFW. Similar things could be done with WLAN in hotels, where the visitor is also known.  For arbitrary public WLANs this would not easily be possible. But in theory one could allow visitors to install a specific government granted VPN on their devices with government issued credentials. If one should trust such a VPN is a different thing.

So in summary: it would be possible from a technical perspective to both block (almost) all local VPN users while still allowing outside visitors to pass through the firewall in most relevant situations.

Apart from that note that it is not even necessary to perfectly block all local users. It is sufficient to forbid the local use of VPN while showing that one can detect most of the VPN use and identify the users behind it. This makes users live in the continuous fear that they are on the watch list, even if their VPN currently works.